# RegEx: Capture only the interior of the capture group

Tags: regex

In the following string, I want to match only 10.00

```
Test(+$15.00)(dsfa) (+$10.00)
```

Right now I have:

```
\([\+|\-]\$(?:[0-9\.]+?)\)$
```

but it captures (+$10.00), I'd like to have only the interior of the capture group.

Edit:
I'm using JS

Comment: You didn't specify which language or variant of regexp, but try this: `\([\+|\-]\$?([0-9\.]+?)\)$`.

Comment: That also capture the (+$ and )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you haven't defined a capturing group in your pattern, you only have literal parenthesis that is totally different. This will give you the result in the capturing group 1 *that is defined with simple parenthesis `(...)`*:

```
\([+-]\$([0-9.]+)\)$
```

*(Note that several characters don't need to be escaped, in particular all special characters are seen as literals inside a character class.)*

In the precedent pattern, I use a capturing group to extract what i want from the whole result. It is possible to obtain only what you want as whole result by using lookarounds (with regex engines that supports lookarounds):

```
(?<=\([+-]\$)[0-9.]+(?=\)$)
```

Comment: Thanks I didn't know about not needing to escape in certain cases. I tried your RegEx on regexpal and it still include (+$ and ) in the capture.

Comment: @RoxanneCourchesne: I suggest you to write the full code in php, with a `print_r($match);`. You will better understand how to use a capturing group.

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to mention I'm using JS so I can't use look behinds. Thanks for the tip, I'll give that a try.

Comment: @RoxanneCourchesne: It's not a problem the first pattern should work with javascript.

Comment: Yeah.. I just realized regexpal was lying to me :(  http://jsfiddle.net/pixy011/efSu3/

Comment: @RoxanneCourchesne: regexpal does not lie, but it highlights only the whole match, not the content of capture groups.

Comment: Yeah I understand, just a figure of speech ;) I know I didn't ask for this in my question... How would I do it if I wanted to have an additional capture group to get the sign? Thanks :)

Comment: @RoxanneCourchesne: I have written in my answer how to define a capturing group.

Comment: Yeah.. ok. I wasn't the capture group part I wasn't sure about but how to use them so it'd do both at the same time. I figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy in JavaScript when using a capturing group. The return value of your test function will be an array where element 0 is the full capture and element 1 is your target result.

```
str = "Test(+$15.00)(dsfa) (+$10.00)"
matches = str.match(/(?:[+-]\$)(\d+\.\d\d)(?:\))$/)
result = matches[1]
```

`matches` here will be `["+$10.00)", "10.00"]` and `result` will be `"10.00"`.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I realized that regexpal was lying to me after Casimir's answer. Though your answer is correct, I'll accept Casimir's cause he had the patience to walk me through my mistakes ;)